# nginx is not working with ansible playbook

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ansible, dockerfile

I'm using ansible to deploy nginx-vts , prometheus, exporter and php everything works fine but nginx keeps stopping and exiting .... if i run the same images with docker compose they tun normally  . the nginx image is based on alpine .

this is my playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: x-vts
    docker_container:
      name: x-nginx
      image: x:latest
      state: started
      volumes:
       - ./php:/var/www/html/x.com
       - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/x.com.conf:ro
      ports:
       - 80:80
  - name: php
    docker_container:
      name: x-php
      image: php:fpm
      state: started
      volumes:
       - ./php:/var/www/html/x.com
  - name: nginx-vts-exporter
    docker_container:
      name: x-Exporter
      image: sophos/nginx-vts-exporter:latest
      state: started
      ports:
       - 9913:9913
      command:
       - NGINX_HOST=http://nginx:80
   - name: prom
    docker_container:
      name: x-prometheus
      image: prom/prometheus:latest
      state: started
      ports:
       - 9090:9090
      volumes:
       - ./monitor/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

this is my nginx config file

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {


    vhost_traffic_status_zone;


    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]     "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format json_combined escape=json '{"time_local":"$time_local", '
        '"proxy_addr":"$remote_addr", '
        '"remote_addr":"$http_x_forwarded_for", '
        '"remote_user":"$remote_user", '
        '"request":"$request", '
        '"status":"$status", '
        '"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent", '
        '"request_time":"$request_time", '
        '"upstream_connect_time":"$upstream_connect_time", '
        '"upstream_header_time":"$upstream_header_time", '
        '"upstream_response_time":"$upstream_response_time", '
        '"http_referrer":"$http_referer", '
        '"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent"}';

    access_log /dev/stdout json_combined; 
     error_log /dev/stderr info;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 11050;
        server_name nginx_vts_status
        access_log off;
        location /status {
            vhost_traffic_status_bypass_limit on;
            vhost_traffic_status_bypass_stats on;
            vhost_traffic_status_display;                 
            vhost_traffic_status_display_format json;
        }
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE :

if i delete the line

```
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

the image launches but it does not work correctly is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your nginx configuration. You should consult to docker logs (eg: docker logs nginx) in order to see nginx stdout. It can help to show where you have syntax errors.

Comment: yes i have found the syntax problem it was with the php container name in the config file it was test-php in my playbook it was x-php now it works fine thank you